# Asynchronously adding the child to stacklayout in xamarin form iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, stacklayout

I am adding the multiple view as child to a stacklayout in a loop. Page is rendering only after all children are being added. i want to show children that are added and a loading sign for the children which are being added.

i am doing like below,

`for(int i= 0; i<30;i++){
myStackLayout.Children.Add(myView);
}`

How to make it asynchronous.

Comment: Where do you add children (in a xaml.cs file I presume) ? From your example I4m not sure it will make a difference to load children asynchronously... It will be fast too.. If children creation process take some times, can you add some code so that we can see the "whole" process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to run your "content/view creation" on a background thread and then when you need to add that content/view to the UI, add it on the main/UI thread (BeginInvokeOnMainThread).

#### Run the content creation on a non-main/UI thread:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var itemsAdded = await AddContentAsync();
});
```

#### Content creation example:

Note: We "show" the `CREATING CONTENT` label, then we create 20 Buttons and add them one at a time on the main/UI thread and also scroll to the new content as it it added, once the content is completed, we scroll back to the top and "hide" the `CREATING CONTENT` label.

```
Task<int> AddContentAsync()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        topLayout.RaiseChild(loading);
        loading.IsVisible = true;
    });

    int itemsAdded = 0;
    for (itemsAdded = 1; itemsAdded < 21; itemsAdded++)
    {
        // Create your dynamic content view....
        var newContentView = new Button
        {
            Text = itemsAdded.ToString(),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            dynamicStackLayout.Children.Add(newContentView);
            (dynamicStackLayout.Parent as ScrollView)?.ScrollToAsync(newContentView, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
        });
    }

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        (dynamicStackLayout.Parent as ScrollView)?.ScrollToAsync(0, 0, true);
        loading.IsVisible = false;
        topLayout.RaiseChild(scrollView);
    });
    return itemsAdded;
}
```

#### Results:

[image]

Comment: This solution did not work for me. it is still loading all the view at the same time.

Comment: @user8671622 The basics are create the view in a background thread and add it in the UI/main thread. If you do that you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I call the async method and created the view in that call.