# Is there a way not to reload the whole AnsoluteLayout when adding views to its Children in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I am using a Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout when I want new controls to be added to it when the user scrolls. Why? Because adding everything when the page 1st opens would take a lot of time since there are lots of items.

I am using an `AbsoluteLayout`, whose `Children` are custom layouts that inherit from `Layout<View>`. Before I add the controls to the `Children` I update their `Bounds` property so that they know where to place themselves.

It looks like every time I call `AbsoluteLayout.Children.Add()`, all the existing children are measured and places, that is, it looks like a full layout cycle is triggered.

Anyone knows how to bypass this? (I have tried `CollectionView`, however it has a known issue of jitter on Android, so i am trying to find an alternative).

Any education/info is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can.Basically,there are two ways.

1.You can create an async method to run your "content/view creation" on a background thread and then when you need to add that child view to the UI, add it on the main/UI thread (BeginInvokeOnMainThread).You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521810/asynchronously-adding-the-child-to-stacklayout-in-xamarin-form-ios).

2.You can add views to its child in [OnAppearing()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method which is prior to the Page becoming visible that renders the page faster.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //add views to its child here
    }
```